# django comments views from scratch

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a blog build on django and doing the comment stuff and I would like to build it from scratch here my views function:

```
def topic_detail(request, slug):
topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, slug=slug)
form = CommentForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.topic = topic
            comment.created_by = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('board:topic_detail', slug=topic.slug)
    else:
        redirect('accounts:login')
else:
    form = CommentForm()
return render(request, 'topic.html', {'topic':topic, 'form':form})
```

my page layout would be:

```
< ............................>

   Something I want to write  

<.............................>

        Comment Field

<.............................>

           Comments
```

So when user presses the button, server will check if that user is authenticated. If yes comment is updated, If no user will be directed to login views. Here the problem, when I'm logged in everything works fine, but when I log out test the views, It does not redirect me to the login views but just reload the page. I would appreciate if you help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `return redirect(....)` instead of just `redirect(...)` to return the actual HttpResponse. Now your code continues to the last line and renders the same page again.